incorrect database name in Rails app when containerized using docker-compose
I have a rails app that I'm trying to containerize locally using docker-compose. I am consistently getting a "database does not exist" error from docker-compose but the database name is a name I'm no longer using. Here is the error message:

db-1   | 2024-08-02 20:41:07.758 UTC [187] FATAL:  database "climate_control" does not exist

The project is named "Climate Control" and the databases are named following the convention "climate_control_[environment name]" - this is my database.yml file:
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  pool: 5

development:
  <<: *default
  host: db
  database: climate_control_development
  username: <%= ENV['POSTGRES_USER'] %>
  password: <%= ENV['POSTGRES_PASSWORD'] %>

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  <<: *default
  database: climate_control_test
  username: climate_control
  password: temp

production:
  database: climate_control_prod
  username: climate_control
  password: temp

Nothing named just "climate_control" in there. I do have a user named "climate_control", but I can't see how that would affect the name of the database the project is trying to use.
I am specifying some environment variables (POSTGRES_DB, POSTGRES_USER, and POSTGRES_PASSWORD) in docker-compose.yml, but POSTGRES_DB is set correctly. Here is the entire file:
# version: '3' # obsolete
services:
  web:
    build: .
    command: bundle exec puma -C config/puma.rb
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
      - "3001:3001" # for debugging
    depends_on:
      - db
    environment:
      RAILS_ENV: development
  db:
    image: postgres:14
    volumes:
      - /opt/homebrew/var/postgresql@16:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: climate_control_development
      POSTGRES_USER: climate_control
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: temp
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "pg_isready -U climate_control"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 5

I have tried rebuilding the docker images:
docker-compose down
docker-compose up --build

I have cleared the Rails cache:
docker-compose exec web rails tmp:cache:clear

I have removed everything from the tmp/ directory:
rm -rf tmp/*

I have searched the codebase for all instances of the string "climate_control" and found only the user names. The entire project is viewable at https://github.com/fredwillmore/climate-control - there's nothing proprietary about it, I'm just trying to create a resume project.
I'm out of ideas, I would welcome any recommendations!

Don’t see any ports for your db container.

That's a good point @dbugger - without specifying the port, it just defaults to 5432, but it would be better to make it clear

I finally figured out my problem - my database files are formatted for postgres 16, but I was using the docker image for postgres 14. The error was coming from the healthcheck which was failing because postgres couldn't load any databases, not even one with a default name of 'climate_control', which is apparently derived from the user name.
